# How many ip addresses can access a web service at a time?

Tags: .net, web-services, hosting, web

I hosted a web service written in ASP.NET. I want to know how many IP addresses/users can access this web service at a time?

I am interested if there is any threshold or after how many connection the problem could start.

Comment: If you are looking for specific benchmarking number, you would need to do this yourself. No one could say this to you. It depends on many factors: your network channel capacity, your code design, app configuration, server hardware etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things. It depends on server configuration, band width etc, if it's more, response of your service will be better. You can set the number of concurrent users in IIS, be default it is Infinite. Secondly, make sure all your client the connection made to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the your servers network capacity, CPU, RAM etc.
So its about your server. You can increase number of clients connected at the same time
by optimizing your code.